# Confusion: $l-\epsilon \leq f(x) \leq l+\epsilon $ . Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary limit of $f$ is $l$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Couple of times I have seen the following in mathematical texts

> $l-\epsilon \leq f(x) \leq l+\epsilon $ . Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary limit of $f$ is $l$.

eg. Introduction to real analysis Bartle and Sherbert pg. 179.
Now this result with strict inequality is quite familiar.
How can we say that when we have $\leq$ as $\epsilon >0$ ?

Comment: I have that book (4th edition), can't find that. Please do give exact reference: chapter, section, etc. Something rather important seems to be missing there, and it is **where is** $\;x\;$ being taken from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Large or strict inequality does not matter.

Assume that for all $\varepsilon>0$, one has $l-\varepsilon\leqslant f(x)\leqslant l+\varepsilon$. Let $\varepsilon>0$, applying the given property to $\displaystyle\frac{\varepsilon}{2}>0$ leads to: $$l-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\leqslant f(x)\leqslant l+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$
In particular, one has $l-\varepsilon<f(x)<l+\varepsilon$.

Conversely, if for all $\varepsilon>0$, one has $l-\varepsilon<f(x)<l+\varepsilon$, it follows that $l-\varepsilon\leqslant f(x)\leqslant l+\varepsilon$.